# JHipster not reflecting changes in HTML with yarn live-reload

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jhipster, yarnpkg, livereload

I am trying out JHipster but I am facing a problem in that live reload with `yarn start` is not reflecting my changes.  I change an html file, the browser reloads, but there are no changes reflected.  What could I be missing.

- JHipster version: 4.5.2 (using Maven)
- IDE: IntelliJ IDEA
- OS: Fedora 26

Comment: I believe you will have to compile your web application as you are using maven, your application architecture does not look like it supports `hot deployment`

Comment: I am running in dev mode, and I have followed the instructions on the site.  I am running the app with `./mvnw` and then `yarn start`.  I edit the home page but nothing changes.  How do I enable this hot deployment then?

Comment: you can use spring devtools for hot reload

Comment: you can check this thread https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/5096

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstall my environment from scratch - nodejs, yarn and jhipster and it worked.  I think the issue might have been caused by updating jhipster when it prompted me for the update.  Thanks guys for your help.

Comment: Seems the problem has returned the moment I generated my model by importing a jdl file.  I noticed that jhipster will ask you to overwrite some files during the process.  This is the command I used: `jhipster import-jdl jhipster-jdl-34.jh --force`

Comment: Also I have noticed that when I run the application with ./mvnw it is no longer accessible on http://localhost:8080.  This seems to be what's causing yarn to keep on serving old files?